# AWS Athena Search for Substring in array using contains() method

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have a column of arrays that are populated with multiple elements. I would like to query these arrays to see if any of their elements contain a specific substring.

I have tried using the `contains()` method for this, which works for exact matches. But I would like to return something similar for a substring.

Comment: Check out the update - added your suggestion. P.S. What engine version do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`any_match`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#any_match):

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(str_arr) AS (
   VALUES   (array['Test1', 'foo', 'bar']),
            (array['foo1']),
            (array['42']),
            (array[])
)

-- query
SELECT *,
       any_match(str_arr, r -> r like '%1%')
FROM dataset;
```

Output:

| str_arr | _col1 |
| --- | --- |
| [Test1, foo, bar] | true |
| [foo1] | true |
| [42] | false |
| [] | false |

Or using combination of [`filter`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#filter) + [`cardinality`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#cardinality) if the `any_match` is not available:

```
-- query
SELECT *,
        cardinality(filter(str_arr, r -> r like '%1%')) > 0 
FROM dataset;
```